# Properties of a memoryless random variable

Tags: probability-theory

Learning about the memoryless property $P(X > s + t | X > t) = P(X > s)$ I was given two properties.

I understand that $P(X > t) > 0$, otherwise the conditional probability is undefined. However I don't understand the second property:

A memoryless random variable $X$ must have the property $P(X \leq 0) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Just thinking out loud:  What if $s = 0$?  Then $$\Pr[X > 0] = \Pr[X > s] = \Pr[X > s + t \mid X > t] = \Pr[X > t \mid X > t] = 1.$$

Comment: ah thank you! That makes sense!